# Why does George Weasley have a toothbrush stuck in his ear?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

In the *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows - Part I*, George walks in on Harry and Ginny kissing. The intriguing thing is that he has a toothbrush stuck in his ear.

**Why?**

Comment: That scene is nothing like what happens in the books, so they won't be any help.

Answer (score 3):

If you look closely, as he enter the room he's using the toothbrush as intended, for cleaning his teeth.

[image: Blurry close up of George brushing his teeth in the background]

When he grabs his tea, he puts the pointy end of the toothbrush in his ear, presumably to avoid having to put the wet end down on an unclean surface while his hands are otherwise occupied.

---

The [script](https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/uploads/scripts/harry-potter-and-the-deathly-hallows-part-1-2010.pdf) describes it thusly, without offering commentary.

> **George wanders in brushing his teeth, pours himself a cup of tea and, sticking the toothbrush in his ear-hole, leans back against the stove for a sip.** Ginny -- sensing something -- opens her eyes and JUMPS. Harry wheels. George winks, tips his cup in their direction.

Comment: God - he brushed his teeth and drank tea  ? He swallowed the toothpaste  ? Or maybe he didn't use toothpaste  ? Grisssly

Comment: And what's more, George's ear got cursed off - has he put it in the no ear - earhole  ?

Comment: @TheMadHatter - This is the magic world. He probably just magicked the toothpaste away. And yes, the script indicates that he put it in the hole.

Comment: In that case what's the us of toothbrush when you can clean your teeth using magic  ?

Comment: @TheMadHatter - Probably the same reason people in HP still walk when they could use brooms to fly, because....er.... whimsy.

Comment: Flying is not that practical - and not everyone is good at it

Comment: @TheMadHatter - All of the Weasley family appear to be excellent fliers. And yet we see them schlepping around just like everyone else

Comment: Percy wasn't such a good flier and I doubt that Molly. ....

Comment: Why does my comment font look smaller than others  ?

Comment: @TheMadHatter - Depends on the device, but usually your own comments are smaller on mobile.